# BackgroundWorker is canceling only once

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem when using BackgroundWorker Cancellation, it's working only once.

In the second time it goes to the finish event.

Do i need to use: backgroundWorker.Dispose() after canceling it?

Here's my code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

//some logic here before calling the copy method

//copy folder method
DirectoryCopy(source, destDirName, true,sender,e);
}

private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{ 
    // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
    // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        Size += Math.Round(((double)file.Length / 1048576), 2);
        string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        int buflen = 1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[buflen];
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream destStream = new FileStream(temppath, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if ((sender as BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    //Progress Logic code
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    ////If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
    if (copySubDirs)
    {
      // Copy Sub-Directories Logic
    }
}
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You cancel the copy!");
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("All the files were copied!");
    }
    btnCopy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    btnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a `BackgroundWorker` has completed, it cannot be restarted. Calling `Dispose()` on it is something you *should* do, but it will NOT allow you to restart it.

You will need to either create a new `BackgroundWorker` or use the more modern `async` style programming (if you're using .Net 4.5 or later).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I created a new BackgroundWorker like you said and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
    BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _BackgroundWorker.DoWork += _BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += _BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        _BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += _BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        _BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    void _BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void _BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void _BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(e);
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Comment: use this code _BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

Answer (score 0):

Some correction to the @Matthew Watson answer.

Once a `BackgroundWorker` has completed, it **CAN** be restarted, you just have to do it correctly. I've done it many times and it always worked.

(In some cases creating new `BackgroundWorkers` over and over again is preferrable, but be carefull to dispose of the resources used. If you're starting multiple workers at once, you should also be careful of the limitations of the threadpool, and that performing operations such as performing operations on the files on the drive simultinously from multiple threads can actually slow your app down)

The working code demonstrating using the same BackgroundWorker multiple times:

```
    BackgroundWorker bg;
    ....
    // Constructor: create the worker (once):
     bg = new BackgroundWorker();
     bg.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
     bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
     bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);


    private void btnStartBgw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!bg.IsBusy)
            bg.RunWorkerAsync();
        else MessageBox.Show("The worker thread is busy!");
    }

    void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DoWorkImpl((BackgroundWorker)sender, e);
    }

    private void DoWorkImpl(BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The work was canceled");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The work was completed successfuly");
        }
    }

    private void btnCancelBgw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bg.IsBusy) bg.CancelAsync();
        else MessageBox.Show("The worker thread is not running!");
    }
```

Also, I think you should reconsider throwing exceptions from your background thread. Instead you can return some error status in the `e.Result`.